# What's the distinction between a defect and a task in Rational Team Concert?

Tags: agile, scrum, task, rtc

Both theses work items seem (at least to me) to be interchangable, with the possible exception that work items may be usable for non-defect changes (such as new functionality).

Is that all there is to it, or is there some more fundamental difference between the two?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @VadimKotov, not that I care any more (since I've moved well beyond RTC) but wouldn't this be covered by the "software tools commonly used by programmers" clause in the help center?

Comment: Please take a look at this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). This question is not unique to software development and this tool can be used not only by programmers - Rational Team Concert can be used by Project managers, testers, etc. For example, JIRA-related questions are off-topic here too, but questions about using JIRA API are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Task is an an over-arching work item type meant to encapsulate a piece of work that does not fall under the umbrellas of the other work items (Defect, Story, Bug Report, and Feature Request, by default).  Typically, new functionality would fall under the Feature Request umbrella.

Work items that might be good candidates for Tasks might include:

- researching the capabilities of a library you are considering adopting,
- building a new test client, or
- filling up the soda machine.

Comment: This is all true, but it's worth noting that the significance is WHAT YOU PLACE ON IT. With RTC you can massage your process definition in any way you see fit, meaning that you can remove or add work item types as appropriate to your project.